# UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 0);

Tags: java, rmi

I do not quite understand what

```
UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 0);
```

is for. Is it to register an object on rmi server or what. Hope someone can shine me some light.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From **[Getting Started Using Java RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/hello-world.html)**

> The static method UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject exports the supplied remote object to receive incoming remote method invocations on an anonymous TCP port and returns the stub for the remote object to pass to clients. As a result of the exportObject call, the runtime may begin to listen on a new server socket or may use a shared server socket to accept incoming remote calls for the remote object.

Comment: In addition to which, this method is automatically called by the constructors of `UnicastRemoteObject`, so if your remote objects extend `UnicastRemoteObject` you don't call it yourself.

Comment: What effect does port 0 have?

Answer (score 6):

Port 0 means it'll pick a random available port for RMI service port. This might be an issue if you're working in a firewalled/NATted environment which requires you to open a port between Client and RMI server hence instead you can specify something other than 0.